# graph created by matplotlib.plot.show closed automatically after the python script finished through command line

Tags: scripts, python, matplotlib

I want to plot a graph and keep it even if the script finished. But it failed after I tried many times.

After script finished executing, the graph created by the show() method will be closed simultaneously.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter([0], [1])
plt.draw()
plt.show(block=False)

for i in range(10):
    plt.scatter([i], [i+1])
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

My version is below:

```
user@ya:~/$ sudo pip freeze | grep matplotlib
matplotlib==2.2.3
user@ya:~/$ sudo pip -V
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Environments:

```
I only execute script in Ubuntu ex: user@ya: python xxx.py
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Can anyone help me? I just want to do like Matlab which won't close the plotted graph even if the script finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a question for stackoverflow.com that askubuntu.com

Anyway, the fix is simple. You called `plt.show()` with `block=False`. So that's why it exists at the end of the script.

Just add a single line like:

```
plt.show()
```

at the end of your script and the plot will stay open.

Comment: I need to close the graph by myself and the script will truly finished. Any way to keep graph alive even the script fininshed?

Comment: Years later, but you can save the current figure as a file: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html